# Ninja: No work to do

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, node-webkit, ninja

I'm trying to build nwjs with Ninja. I built the code a few times before, however, this issue I cannot resolve.

I get the following Ninja message:

```
ninja -C out/Release nw -j4
ninja: Entering directory `out/Release'
ninja: no work to do.
```

Any suggestions?

There should be work to do. I haven't built the code yet.